# People reacting with anger to my trying to get rid of meetings that should be emails

Tags: colleagues, meetings

I'm invited to a lot of "meetings that should be emails". I'm currently doing a lot of unpaid overtime because of, among others, that. I have a list of tasks to complete. In a typical workday I can't start even one of them since I spend time in not necessary meetings planned with a very short notice.

So colleague Sam (my peer) schedules a meeting in 4 hours with title "Current situation" or "Project - next steps" or something similarly vague. No description.

I've no idea what the meeting is to be about and judging by who proposed it there's a huge chance he didn't invite the right persons or he will want me to "explain him AWS" (he has a non-technical role on a technical project. He wants to be explained a lot of technicalities).

When I ping him and ask what the topic of the meeting is, he says, he wanted to get diagram A and ask about the process for B. I say: "Let me send you the diagram. I haven't even started designing a process for B, so I really can't say anything about it". I propose that we cancel the meeting if that's all.

He accusses me of not being a team player and working in silos.

How should I cover my ass in this case? I'm trying to help everyone, but my workload is currently unbearable and useless meetings that shouldn't happen contribute to that.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127591/discussion-on-question-by-user216856-people-reacting-with-anger-to-my-trying-to).

Comment: For the repeat offenders... have you tried asking them to start with an email request instead of a meeting? Some people think that everything needs to be a meeting to get your full attention and get *their* stuff done on time (with less importance on interrupting your work schedule).

Comment: There are other similar questions/answers on this site; maybe you'll find some of them useful? https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3485/what-is-the-appropriate-way-to-deal-with-meeting-overload, https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/137156/98765, https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/126168/reject-many-meeting-invitations-without-upsetting-the-senders.

Comment: The title mentions "people" in plural getting angry, but your example is only one person.
I think it is important to know whether it is a single person that is difficult or the whole company culture being meeting heavy.

Answer (score 105):

1. Talk to your manager. Make sure you are aligned on your meeting load AND the impact it has on your deliverables. Ask for advice on how to respond to meeting requests that are (in your opinion) not useful and how to reduce number of meetings to the "target".
2. Stop the unpaid overtime.
3. Block out work time on your calendar. Make sure there is not more time for meetings available then you are willing to spend on meetings. You can always make room for something important if needed.
4. You can decline meetings, but it's best done "politely". Example *Thanks for the invite but I currently have a tight deadline on project X. Can this wait a bit? In the meantime here is the documentation for A. I haven't done anything on project B yet, maybe we can meet once there is something to actually review*

Comment: I recently blocked out 11:00 AM to 1:00 PM on my calendar, every week day. People saw my calendar being empty around lunch time, so they kept scheduling meetings during that time slot. I use that time slot to check my email, get real work done, sometimes run errands, and occasionally have a nice lunch so I don't get hangry with my coworkers. I still get scheduled for (and accept) meetings in that time slot, but not nearly as many as before I blocked it out.

Comment: Blocking out a chunk of time is a great idea. It makes people think. You'll still have to occasionally accept meeting invites during that blocked-out time, but at least they'll ask. "Dave, I really need to have a meeting with you, and the only time I can do that is noon tomorrow." My response will be "Okay, fine. But please don't make a habit out of it."

Comment: Someone told me #3 and I wish it happened years sooner; it's truly incredible how simple but effective it is at improving your productivity. I'll also add: you can set your status to "Busy" during those blocks and have notifications suppressed so you have uninterrupted time to think and work.

Comment: #2 is a "world view" solution. In the US, a certain amount of unpaid overtime is expected of white collar/salaried/exempt employees. Sometimes, it's even scheduled/demanded by management (often accompanied by company provided dinner) to get through a critical project. It's often (somewhat) offset by more flexibility in hours (knock off early on a Friday after a long week, take a whole day off w/o taking PTO, leave for a personal appt w/o PTO, etc - usually prompted by a reasonable manager). That said, working 7am-9pm or more, especially for long periods, is ridiculous.

Comment: @FreeMan I think that is important to the answer of the question. Is the OP salaried/exempt? If not, then stop working unpaid overtime. In some jurisdictions, and for some customers, it's illegal. If the OP is, then it's not 'unpaid overtime' it's work, deal with it, and change your mental viewpoint to match, or quit and be employed as hourly or non-exempt.

Comment: There is a big problem with unpaid overtime. It puts a **price of zero on your time**. This can be a reasonable deal to leave a good impression if done occassionally and circumstances really require it. But this should not become a routine and certainly not be a fixup to wasting time by unnecessary meetings in the first place. No matter whether legal or not, expected or not. #1 and #2 are targeting exactly this issue by first getting management into the boat and then stopping unpaid work

Comment: @Manziel A lot of companies in certain industries (big tech, big law, etc.) view it as they are paying for that time--the salary is high enough that it would cover a reasonable (or even high) hourly wage for that many hours a week, even though it isn't broken down as being per hour and no particular hours are specified in the contract.

Comment: @Manziel Adding to the previous comment, many employers expect employees with a high salary (e.g., close to six figures, and in some cases well into then six figure range) to work more than 40 hours per week. The work week is 40 hours for accounting reasons only. When those employees take take paid time off (a holiday, a vacation, being sick), they are paid as if their work day was eight hours. When they work, those employees are also paid as if their work day was only eight hours long, but it's typically longer, especially at crunch time.

Comment: @user3067860 Tough, that's not what the employment contract says. As long as employees continue to bend over and accept this abuse, it will continue.

Comment: @IanKemp: You're assuming that there are employment contracts. Having worked for multiple US-based employers, I've not once had a contract that specified an "hour limit" for full-time employment.

Comment: @FreeMan if it's counter-balanced with free time elsewhere that is not unpaid overtime just a flexible work schedule with flexibility on both ends. If there is an expectation of regular unpaid overtime the right thing to do for everyone is to push back instead of supporting such a bullshit culture. (It's one thing to do overtime because you want to and another to follow expectations). Sure there are exceptions but they need to be that. Are there risks? Sure. But giving in has risks and known drawbacks free of charge on top.

Comment: In some environments, "unpaid overtime" is normal (and legal).

Comment: "Expectations" are always fine-tuned by both parties. If enough people stop working for free, companies will no longer expect this. Fllexible arrangements that allow you to take some days off based on overtime are a different thing. And regarding "crunch time"...in my opinion the amount of crunch time correlates with bad management. I would not work for a company that requires me to suspend my life for weeks just because somebody messed up release planning

Answer (score 42):

The problem is not the meetings per se, the problem is that you are doing unpaid overtime work because you are unable to complete your tasks during normal working hours.

Meetings are a part of every job.  Yes there are meetings that should probably have been an email but you never know until you actually attend the meeting.

It's great to be a team player, but not at the expense of your time or your job.  If you have assigned tasks that need to be done, then decline any meeting invites that would prevent you from completing your tasks *during normal business hours*.

If the meeting organizers have any issue with this, you can direct them to your manager and let your manager decide if your time is best spent in a meeting or actively working on your tasks.  Under no circumstances, however, should you be working unpaid overtime to complete your tasks.  If you cannot complete your tasks during normal working hours, due to a meeting or anything else, you need to speak with your manager and let them know why the proposed deadline is unfeasible.

If you are expected to do unpaid overtime at this company, it may be time to start looking for a new company to work for.

Comment: It's two separate problems, right? If OP had not mentioned the unpaid overtime, we would be addressing the unneeded meetings issue directly.

Comment: @Corey  Not necessarily.  "Unneeded" is  a subjective term; one person's "unneeded" meeting could be another person's "mission critical" meeting.  A number of years back, I was working at a company where our processes were completely FUBAR, and nobody had any idea what was going on.  In particular, the developers (me) were getting new requirements from PM every day because the customers kept changing their asks.  So one day, I called a meeting between my team, PM, my boss, and the customers, to hash out the details.  After the meeting, the lead customer emailed  me to say how  productive...

Comment: ... and great that meeting was and how much we got done.  PM agreed, and so did my team.  My boss, on the other hand, called me into his office  and told me how terrible and how much of a waste of time that meeting was and how nothing got  accomplished.  It's definitely a matter of perspective.

Comment: @Ertai87 OP is asking specifically about unneeded meetings in the objective sense. There is nothing to indicate that perspectives are out of alignment. I have worked with this type of offender before, and we created policies that targeted his behavior specifically. Let's take OP at their word.

Comment: @Corey There are plenty of threads on this forum where an OP says something is "unnecessary" or "unneeded" but when you drill into  what the OP is actually talking about, it turns out those "unneeded" things are actually very valuable and the  OP is  working off  a bad premise.  I'm going to choose to not take OP at their word on this one.  "Unnecessary" is a  subjective term. (I'm also not going to discount OP's claim; they may be right, but without more information I would not say that OP's  meetings are blanket "unnecessary")

Comment: be the meetings unneeded or not, I find "you never know until you actually attend the meeting" hard to believe. Like OP said, I think if you ask what the meeting will be about, you will usually have a grasp if it's needed or not.

Comment: "If you are expected to do unpaid overtime at this company, it may be time to start looking for a new company to work for." If the OP is in the US, often a 45 hour work-week is _expected_, even though the pay is only for 40 hours. I'm not defending that, just pointing out a fact. Especially now that people get corporate email on their phones, I get emails from my boss at 7am and 10pm and while they're "on vacation". I don't encourage it, and I don't participate, but it's a fact of life in the US.

Comment: No.  The problem (from a productivity point of view) is that the OP seems to be required to waste time in meetings.  Meetings are almost always non-productive for the majority of those attending.

Answer (score 14):

You are conflating a handful of problems. You can solve them and still be a team player. You are also experiencing a communication problem that is being masked by your current specific problem.

Too many meetings, can't get anything done

1. Block your calendar for focus time. You could even get buy-in from your manager. "Boss I'd like to devote 50% of each day to focus time. If that's alright with you I'll block my calendar."

Sam needs to get better at some things

2. Sam could use some guidance on scheduling meetings in a way that better respects people's time. Completing async tasks outside of meetings, More notice, really good descriptions, more attention to invite lists. You could provide this feedback directly and/or to his boss. I prefer one effort at direct then escalation to management.
3. Sam is asking you to train him. Is that your job? Some explanation is reasonable, too much is not. Does his job role require that he know AWS. Perhaps he needs to train up. If he lacks knowledge he needs, you could help, you could point him at training resources, you could suggest to his manager that he could benefit from specific training.

Too much

4. You may have more work than can be completed in normal working hours. Perhaps you could offload some of that along with guarding your time for focus hours. Doing so could free you up to both complete your tasks and be a team player. Everybody likes a team player.

Big picture you need closer relationships so you can safely have difficult conversations.

5. I had a colleague who once answered my question with "I know the answer to that, I also know that you know where to look it up." I really appreciated it because it taught me how to find the line between expedient and dependent. We could only have such a candid conversation because we trusted each other. You may wish to work at building rapport with Sam so you can have candid conversations with him. If this were me I'd buy him a beer. Talk about other things, but the important stuff will surface. With a little bit more mutual empathy y'all can start to have the important conversations: "Bro, I'm slammed. I can't be in 6 hours of meetings every day and you're not helping", to which he might say "Bro I can't get anything done on my end because I'm waiting on info from you." at which point you might be able to meet in the middle.

Answer (score 10):

**Filling your calendar with time slots allocated to important tasks** works wonders in a situation like yours. Say, you have an important task A which you have to finish by the end of the day, and it takes 4 hours. First thing in the morning, find a 4-hour slot and book it in your calendar with "Working on A" event.

Now, if Sam needs a meeting with you during these 4 hours, it will be very clear to everyone that you will attend this meeting at the expense of A not being completed today. If Sam asks you to reschedule this "Working on A" event, you honestly try to find another 4-hour slot, and if there is none left, write an e-mail to the stakeholder of A saying:

> Hi boss, Sam needs me on his meeting, which means A will have to wait until tomorrow. Is that OK?

Or, if the stakeholder of A is not very responsive, you can ask Sam to get the stakeholder's approval before you accept, so that their unresponsiveness would not be your problem anymore.

If the stakeholder says yes, you can do A tomorrow, no reason for overtime. If they say no, forward their reply to Sam and deny Sam's invitation.

Comment: What's your recommendation if the "boss" doesn't reply to the conflict inquiry (in time)?

Comment: @DanielR.Collins I usually put it on the inviter... "Inviter, Sorry but I've been assigned Project A as my highest priority. Your meeting conflicts with my ability to complete Project A on time and so will need to be run by my manager. Once you get my manager's approval and they inform me that I can attend your meeting instead, I'll accept." or something like that. Now the inviter has to explain the meeting to my boss and get my boss' signoff that their meeting is more important than me doing tasks towards my high pri project. I've been using this successfully for years.

Comment: @JeffC Good idea, I'll add this to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

One of the most powerful words in our lexicon is "No".

Inform your colleague via email that your work takes priority and you don't have time for these additional meeting requests scheduled outside the normal work day which you don't believe add value to the company. Make sure your manager is CC'd on the email.

You work for the company, not your colleague.

Comment: Doesn't always work. Some people get upset when you are "blunt" with them. You have to "sweeten" your no. But that doesn't always work either.

Comment: @speciesUnknown People who can't handle blunt facts are generally people it is best to ignore or sideline.

Comment: That depends entirely on who they are. Don't make my mistake and let it become an HR issue.

Comment: @speciesUnknown A colleague demanding meetings outside of work hours *without even asking if you have time for said meeting* is not being reasonable.

Comment: @user1666620 in the comments the OP says their manager schedules meetings outside of work hours

Comment: Trust me. You have to sugar coat things - I've recently discovered that being blunt is grounds for an HR complaint.

Comment: @speciesUnknown this is very cultural, though. And there are ways of being direct without being impolite. A simple "I have other priorities I need to focus on at this moment - other deliveries that were already committed to management will be sidelined if I shift my focus to this project" And if OP followed the advice and blocked time in the calendar, they can also add "My availability is up-to-date, send me an invite in any free spot and I'm happy to help you"

Comment: @speciesUnknown: Some people get upset when you're blunt with them?  But maybe they NEED to get upset as a motivator for changing their behavior.  And since most of the OP's meeting requests seem to come from peers rather than managers, refusing ought not to present a problem: you simply tell the appropriate manager that peer's behavior is keeping you from doing productive work.

Comment: @jamesqf the problem with being blunt (or what people typically understand by it) is that it implies you know that you have authority in the matter and read the situation right. If the peer has a right to ask, because the manager assumes OP is training the peer or their mentor etc. just telling them off makes OP the one who blocks the team from getting things done. If being blunt includes offering a way out, like clarifying with the manager what takes priority, that's not an issue, but here it seems to be the "go away, I'm busy and know my stuff is more important than yours" variant.

Comment: @jamesqf when you read the situation right and your stuff has higher prio, just telling a colleague off might not be a direct problem, but  it can easily come off as willingly unhelpful to the colleague when you don't give them a way out - some day you might need their help and then it's easily "payback time".

Answer (score 5):

Stop overtime.

You set no location so I don't know if at all possible, but unpaid overtime is not mandatory where I work.

Keep your boss up to date with your progress (or lack of it) and the reason (long hours in meetings) and let the people in charge decide.

Comment: Some amount of unpaid overtime has been pretty much expected with every employer I've worked for. People have been dinged for not providing enough UOT.

Comment: @DavidHammen I guess you're talking about the US? As a counterexample, the notion of "unpaid overtime" does not exist at all in the labor laws of some EU countries. As the answer says, we don't know the location.

Comment: @TooTea Since the OP wrote about unpaid overtime, we can pretty much guess that the OP does not live in Europe. As you wrote, unpaid overtime is illegal in much of Europe. On the other hand, unpaid overtime is standard operating procedure for salaried employees in much of the US.

Comment: @TooTea The OP mentioned in comments that they are sometimes scheduled for 7:00 PM meetings, and that their boss sees them online at 7:00 AM and 9:00 PM. That would never happen in Europe. It often happens in high tech companies in the US. I'm assuming US, and probably somewhere on the west coast.

Comment: @DavidHammen This happens in the US, but I do not believe it is common.  Regardless of location, it is dumb - even if it is legal.

Comment: @emory For those who work with people who live in Europe or Asia, people in the US are going to be subjected to 4:00 AM or 10:00 PM meetings. It is what it is.

Comment: @DavidHammen: *That would never happen in Europe* I am not sure which Europe you are talking about but the one I know and work in and with (France, Germany, Italy, Poland, UK) this is common. For instance, in France, you have meetings that start at ~9:00 (because school & children drop off) and end at ~19:00. The law is that you have to have 11 hours of uninterrupted rest.

Comment: I'm pretty sure unpaid overtime is not mandatory anywhere in the world. It may be expected from you, and you may be the first to be let go if you refuse to do it, but you cannot be terminated for cause if you refuse.

Answer (score 5):

The others answered what you should do:
Speak with your manager.

You seem surprised that people get angry when you tell them this meeting should be an email. So I want to focus on the communication aspect.

Compare these two replies to a meeting invitation.

a) This meeting should be an email, write one.

b) Hey, I have a lot of work and tight schedules right now. Sadly, I don't have time for this meeting now, but I will have next week. I'd appreciate if you write a detailed agenda for this, so I can come prepared. If you don't want to wait, you could email me your questions and I'll try to find a few minutes to answer them.

If this doesn't work for you, please involve my manager so he can change priority of my tasks.

Reply b) is much more likely to be received with understanding. Because it gives the other party choices, they still feel like they have some sort of control. Now your preferred path (email) also has upsides for them: It's faster than waiting and likely less effort than convincing your manager that this meeting is more important than some other task you do.

Your manager should be aware of your tasks and their priority. And if your manager says this meeting can wait, well, you tried to be a team player, right? It's your manager's job to prioritize your tasks and to protect you so you can actually do them. So let him say no for you.

Comment: You misunderstood in a very strange way. I have never told anyone that "this meeting should be an email, write one". "Meeting should be an email" is an expression I've used in the title of the thread here.

Answer (score 1):

### Do not say "No," but instead get the team to say "No."

If the team says **no** to the useless meeting, then it is the person scheduling the meeting that is not the team player.  The problem is that the team has given complicit consent to working ridiculous hours and attending terrible meetings.  Since the question is focused on the meetings only for this answer I will be ignoring the working overtime and focus on getting the team on board to saying no to these meetings.

I am assuming not everyone on the team is scheduling these meetings.  As such begin having one-on-one conversations with those who are good about not scheduling excessive meetings but get dragged into them.  Ask them if these meetings are impacting their work, or interfering with their ability to do things outside of work.  The goal is to ask questions that get them to open up and vent about their own frustrations.

If the majority of the team in private is willing to vent about their frustrations about the meetings then at either the next retrospective or equivalent raise this and get the team to agree and say no to any meeting after X time, meetings without fixed and detailed agendas will be rejected, and if the objectives of the meeting are achievable outside of the meeting then the meeting is rejected.  At that point anyone who does this is no longer the team player and if you decline the meeting you have the team backing you.

If the team has no concept of a retrospective or equivalent then a special meeting needs to be scheduled to "go over ideas for optimize team performance" or something similarly vague but still meaningful.

Now if the boss' boss is scheduling meetings after 7:00 pm (as mentioned in comments) there is not too much you can do about it.  The best course of action is to explain to them how the team is trying to establish things like no meetings after X time and if they can do the same it would set an amazing and great example to everyone (brown nosing and praising them as much as possible if that is effective).

Comment: Getting buy-in from others is good.  But it is also possible some of those others are guilty of scheduling equally useless meetings, and even know it.

Answer (score 0):

This takes some guerilla tactics. It seems like you are in a situation where other people in the company does not respect your time. They seem to have different priorities from you -- you want to deliver your assigned task, they seem to want something different. And, to speed forward to the last point, your manager is the judge on priorities, not you.

So start by working on the time aspect. You will talk to your manager about this later, but when talking to managers *always bring facts*.

1. Become very good at reporting your time. Keep a detailed diary down to how every 15 minutes of your day is spent. Use a program, a notebook or whatever works for you. Maybe set an alarm to go off every one hour and note down the quarters before that. Note down what project / what task or similar and what activity you did. This will take about 5% of your time initially (three minutes per hour), but it will pay back greatly. In the end of the week summarise the time spent (say, 10 minutes every week).
2. Become better at planning your time. Once a week, sit down and plan the coming week. Write down the priorities you have -- what you expect to deliver or achieve. My suggestion is to have less than 10 points - if you are a developer maybe only three points. Check at the end of week how far you got on your priorities. This will take you about 10 minutes every week.
3. Become better at forecasting time, both in man-hours and in calender days. Work on breaking down larger chunks of work into smaller pieces. As a developer, a task should always be less than two calendar weeks. Check afterwards how good your assumption was and slowly (months, years) learn to improve.
4. In order to be able to do 3. you need to allocate your time to tasks. Do not forget to allocate time to things like planning, follow up, meetings and so on. Do this on a weekly basis and check afterwards how the allocation turned out, remember the time reporting in 1. (takes about 10 minutes).
5. Always prepare for meetings, and always do the paper work afterward. Take at least 15 minutes before a meeting to prepare the things to be discussed (or what you guess will be discussed). Prepare a minutes document. In the meeting, write minutes, detailing how long time each "thing" were discussed. After the meeting take 15 minutes to fix up the minutes document and distribute it to the participants. Store it for later usage. A good way to show the unpredictability of the meeting is to include the invitation exactly as you received it, including the time it arrived. In the minutes be short and factual. Do not blame anyone, never say things like the meeting was unnecessary (an intelligent reader will understand that anyway).

   My experience in physical meetings is that the best way is to open the minutes on a screen seen by all participants and actually write the minutes in the meeting. This will make the meeting go slower, but it is worth it. A few meetings later, people will prepare and distribute material ahead of the meeting.
6. After about two weeks, it is the time to take the facts to your manager and discuss priorities. Send him the material and questions in advance (be the good inviter you want others to be). Is the time reporting you did the best way to use *your* time for the best of the *company*? You now have facts showing what you planned do to, what you actually did, how it effected your deliveries and facts on what contribution the meetings had to the *company*. Remember you are employed to contribute your full time to helping the company achieve its goals, and you are not aware of the full picture.
7. There are other tactics to protect your time. One of them is to schedule recurring meetings, say every week. Put the time in the calender, and refer all short questions to these meetings (no need for extra meetings on short notice). In addition to minutes, keep an itemized list on Activities -- what to do, who should do it, when it should be done, and details if necessary. Start each meeting by noting the status on each of the open points. This will seem unnecessary and takes time, but in my experience it actually saves a lot of time. Move closed items to the minutes of the meeting. Be extra careful to always write decisions into the meeting.

Comment: Re *"write decisions into the meeting"*: Do you mean *"write decisions into the minutes"* (or *"write decisions in the minutes"* or *"include decisions in the minutes"*)? Or something else?

Comment: @PeterMortensen : sorry, I mean write decisions into the minutes.

Answer (score -12):

> I'm currently doing a lot of unpaid overtime

Stop that immediately.

Never, ever, ever work more than your standard 35 hours - ever - for any reason.

Comment: Where do you live, and in which field of work? There are a number of high tech companies in the US where salaried people are paid for working 40 hours per week but are expected to work 60 hours per week, minimum. There are other high tech companies that poach burnt-out employees from these companies with the promise that they'll only have to work 50 hour weeks. I've never heard of a high tech company with a 35 hour work week.

Comment: @DavidHammen While OP doesn't mention their country, it's entirely possible they are in a first world nation.

Comment: In some countries lunch is not included into your 40 work hours. This means you stay 9 hours per day at work, with 8 working hours and 1 more hour of unpaid time you spend on lunch.

Comment: 40 hours a week with unpaid lunches is the standard in my part of Canada. But even ignoring the standard hours issue, this answer does not fully address the OP's question.

Comment: @Alex That's very true. In some jurisdictions, having people working on their unpaid lunch break is grounds for overtime payment too